# Using Restler3, how to log requests/responses

Tags: php, restler

Is there currently any means of capturing an incoming request and response, and logging that?  I see that there are 'preCall' and 'postCall' methods, however, some of my API methods are not strictly named by HTTP verbs.

For example, in my 'Players' class, I have 'get' method which returns one player for a given player_id, and 'getPlayers' which returns all players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There sure is!

Here is some code that I pieced together from some other SO questions:

```
$r->onComplete(function () use ($r) {
// Don't log Luracast Restler Explorer recources calls
if ( ! preg_match('/resources/', $r->url)) {
    $success = $r->responseCode == 200;        
    $request = $r->getRequestData();
    $info = array(
        'base'              => $r->getBaseUrl(),
        'method'            => $r->requestMethod,
        'url'               => $r->url,
        'api_key'           => NULL,
        'route'             => $r->apiMethodInfo->className.'::'.$r->apiMethodInfo->methodName,
        'data'              => $request['request_data'],
        'ip'                => User::getIpAddress(),
        'referer'           => (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']: ''),
        'http_status_code'  => $r->responseCode,
        'response'          => $success ? '' : $r->exception->getErrorMessage()
        );
        print_r($info); // replace with your logging function here

}
```

});